# Delay when changing UINavigationController title with swift

Tags: iphone, swift, xcode6, uistoryboard

Ok, I have tried different ways to update the title in the UINavigationBar but there is always a delay.

I have a Navigation Controller that is a root view controller of a table view. I have tried different ways to change the title and try to get the UINavigationBar to redraw, but there is a delay of ~10 seconds.

```
//I have tried different ways to change the title:
self.title = str
//and
@IBOutlet var tableTitle: UINavigationItem!
self.tableTitle.title = str

//as well as different ways to convince it to redraw
self.view.window?.rootViewController?.setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate()
//and
self.tableTitle.awakeFromNib()
```

I forgot that this was being done from a dataTaskWithURL, so it needed to be called from the main thread.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async), this function submits a block for asynchronous execution on a dispatch queue and returns immediately, take a look in the following code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        // Change your title here
})
```

I hope this help you.